Getting error "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' " when cloning git repository
I am getting an error in my debian terminal when cloning a git repository.
Here is the command:
git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/organization-example/RMC701%20(CBLPE00520)/Terraform-CB-connection-Vault

I am gettting this error:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Is this because of the project name in Azure Devops ? RMC701%20(CBLPE00520)
I did not find any solution yet

Please make sure to read the info of any tag you use. In this case the [tag:bash] tag you used says "IMPORTANT NOTE: Do not ask a bash question until after you have copy/pasted your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixed all of the issues it tells you about." and if you do that then shellcheck will tell you exactly what the errors are, how to fix them, and provided references to articles about those errors.

( has special meaning to bash, similar to i.e. $ or {.

Yes, the problem is caused by the project name, more precisely because of the parentheses "( )" in the project name.
The parentheses "( )" could be recognized as a group of command lines if you do not pass them as part of a string.
To avoid this issue, you need to use double or single quotes to surround the project name or the whole URL like as one of the command lines below:
git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/organization-example/'RMC701%20(CBLPE00520)'/Terraform-CB-connection-Vault

or
git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/organization-example/"RMC701%20(CBLPE00520)"/Terraform-CB-connection-Vault

or
git clone 'git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/organization-example/RMC701%20(CBLPE00520)/Terraform-CB-connection-Vault'

or
git clone "git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/organization-example/RMC701%20(CBLPE00520)/Terraform-CB-connection-Vault"


The %20 is also suspicious. Maybe someone should learn about good naming convention before creating examples (and distributing them). -- To the OP: if you can, change documentations or tools (or companies). Do not learn from bad teachers: it will be difficult to beak bad habits
